# how to display global loading for all axios request in nuxt plugin

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to display my custom loading on all axios request globally

for that I've made a plugin for axios to call it like this

**plugins/axios.js**

```js
    export default function ({ app, $axios, redirect, store }, inject) {
    
    
        $axios.onRequest(config => {
            this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
        })
    
        $axios.onError(error => {
            this.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
        })
    
      
    }
```

but It get error because we don't have **this** here .

so how can I modify this code ?

Answer (score 1):

The nuxt loading property is used to track pages load status. This is an internal component that you can replace with custom component:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  loading: '~/components/YourLoadingComponent.vue'
}
```

But it is not the same feature that set a loading status for your HTTP requests. I recomend you to create a component to manage the loading status for your HTTP requests, and you can manage the current loading status with Vuex, and then modify the store from your `axios.js` plugin.

```js
// axios.js plugin
export default function ({ $axios, store }) {

  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    store.dispatch('setLoadingStatus', true)
  })

  $axios.onError(error => {
    store.dispatch('setLoadingStatus', false)
  })

}
```

Then you Vuex store can manage the request status:

```js
// store/index.js file
export const state = () => ({
  isRequestLoading: false
})

export const mutations = {
  saveLoadingStatus(state, payload) {
    state.isRequestLoading = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setLoadingStatus({ commit }, status) {
    commit('saveLoadingStatus', status)
  }
}
```

And very simple example component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="isRequestLoading">Is Loading</p>
    <p v-else>Request completed</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      isRequestLoading: (state) => state.isRequestLoading
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

You can set a loading bar or spinner to display in your window inside this component.